# Sleeping in kernel worker thread

Tags: kernel, interrupt

I am reading about how interrupts defer work through workqueues.

From what I understood, the interrupt will enqueue work into a workqueue, and this will then be processed by a kernel worker thread.

My question is in the context of executing the work within the kernel `worker_thread`.

- If this task voluntarily sleeps, will the `worker_thread` process other work it has in its queue?
- What if the work + worker thread relinquishes control involuntarily (e.g. preemptive scheduling), when restarted will the worker thread finish the work before moving on to the next task?